# name 'rospy' is not defined

Tags: python, ros, catkin, rospy

I am trying to run a ros package named - SpartonCompassIMU using rosrun.
i do the following :

```
catkin_make
source /.../devel/setup.bash
rosrun SpartonComapssIMU SpartonCompassIMU.py
```

it gives the following error:

```
rospy.init_node('SpartonDigitalCompassIMU')
NameError: name 'rospy' is not defined
```

when i run python 2.7 and type in:

```
import rospy
```

it works just fine

How can i fix this?

Comment: Did you `import rospy` in `SpartonCompassIMU.py`?

Comment: also, which version of ROS is installed? are you sure ROS is running on Python 2.7?

Comment: I quickly googled "SpartonCompassIMU.py" and the [file I found on github](https://github.com/udmamrl/SpartonCompassIMU/blob/master/src/SpartonCompassIMU.py) has the `import rospy` commented out. So the reason why `rospy` is not found is that it is indeed not imported.

Comment: I tried it. It resulted in multiple errors at the time. I got it working somehow. Thanks.